# What is the most cost efficient way to invest in overseas stocks as a UK citizen?

Tags: stocks, united-kingdom, foreign-exchange, foreign-income, cost-cutting

I wish to invest in multiple US-based mutual funds and companies. I already have an account with Charles Stanley Direct for my UK-based funds and was disappointed to see that I couldn't use their service for this purpose.

The way I understand it I have 2 options:

#### 1)    Find a broker that lets me buy overseas shares in sterling (£)

- Dealing fee and commission fee for the currency conversion when buying and selling
- Commission fees apply to dividends as well
- Since account is in sterling, stocks can go into an ISA

#### 2)    Open an overseas account

- Need a separate service to conduct currency conversion (but this would typically be cheaper than the fees from option 1)
- Shares *cannot* contribute to an ISA *(HM Revenue & Customs' rules forbid foreign currency in an ISA)*
- Shares *can* contribute to a SIPP
- Need to file a W-8BEN document (?)

---

At first glance it seems like Option 2 is the cheaper option. Is this correct?

Are there other options? Are there any gotchas I have missed?

Comment: Note that for option1 you'll probably need to file a W-8BEN too e.g http://www.hl.co.uk/shares/share-dealing/overseas-share-dealing-service .  And I'd be surprised if you could invest in mutual funds via option1 (ETFs shouldn't be a problem).  I'm not aware of any other options than the ones you list though.